# Customize Stripe payment intent forms when using Stripe for Craft Commerce (commerce-stripe) plugin

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, plugin-commerce-stripe

Is it possible to style the fields contained in the Stripe Intents form when using [this plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe)?

Currently the form seems to load with all the interactions but with minimal styling. I'd like to have the CC form styles identical to other form elements on the page but having a difficult time figuring out how to do so.

Any help would be much appreciated!

This is what the form currently looks like (card holder info are from the twig template and the plugin fields below)

[image]

I'm using the latest Craft 3 + Commerce 2.

Comment: I've gotten as far as digging through `vendor/craftcms/commerce-stripe/src/web/assets/intentsform/js/paymentForm.js` and `vendor/craftcms/commerce-stripe/src/templates/paymentForms/intentsForm.html` as well as the stripe element documentation on styling the form.

The only styling I can do within paymentForm.js seems to be the base styles such as fontSize etc, and all the examples on [Stripe Elements Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/migrating#formatting-customization) shows styling within a separate CSS file, which is the part I'm completely stumped on.

Comment: This question has been asked before, I have [provided an answer on that post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/customizing-stripe-payment-form-for-craft-commerce-2-subscription/33168#33168).